# Exception in thread main - object oriented

Tags: java, class, object, exception, object-oriented-analysis

I wrote the class "Fraction", and one of the functions I tried to execute wad readFunction as follows:

```
public static Fraction readFraction() {
    String s = StdIn.readString();
    Fraction f = null;
    while (f == null) {
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
        try {
            int lineIndex = s.indexOf("/");
            if (lineIndex != -1) {
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(0, lineIndex));
                denominator = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(
                        lineIndex + 1, s.length()));
            } else {
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(StdIn.readString());
                denominator = 1;
            }
            f = new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            StdOut.println("Please enter a valid answer:");
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            StdOut.println("Can't divide by zero, please enter a valid answer:");
        }
    }
    return f;
```

I get a "Exception in thread main" note. I wrote another class from which I call this function and the mentioned error above is what I get.
For each value I insert it gives my another exception. For example when I insert '4' (which is llegal) I get:http://tinypic.com/r/2m3mv6w/8

I'll be more than happy to get some leads about my mistake. 
Thank you!

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Continue reading. You read the boring part, not the part that points to the exact line of code, with a descriptive name on the exception.

Comment: Exception in thread main.

Comment: @Mic - and the rest of it is ...

Comment: You might be interested in this short [java debugging tutorial](http://keysersblog.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/debugging-java-code-a-beginners-guide/) I wrote. It starts with how you read a stack trace.

Comment: @StephenC For each value I insert it gives my another exception. For example when I insert '4' (which is llegal) I get:

Comment: @Mic you get what? Can you paste that in question please?

Comment: @StephenC For each value I insert it gives my another exception. For example when I insert '4' (which is llegal) I get:http://tinypic.com/r/2m3mv6w/8

Comment: I told you to keep reading :p `NoSuchElementException` is the first valuable information. Also, add the trace to your question, not as a link to a picture in the comments..or in the question. On a side note: your title should be along the lines of _"NoSuchElementException Scanner..."_

Answer (score 0):

"Exception in thread main" can be a lot of things, though. It is only teeling you that an exception occurred in the main thread of your program. It does not tell you what type of error it was, and where it happens.
That's why you should add the stack trace of the exception. If you don't see the stacktrace, please check that the catch block of your calling to the function has something like `e.printStackTrace();`.

The only thing I can tell from what you post, is that the Exception is a [RunTimeExcpetion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), because your method does not declare any Exception.

But, as you might check from javadoc, there are a lot of RunTimeExceptions...